# Objective-C If Statement Comparing Floats not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, if-statement

This is literally the weirdest thing I have ever encountered. So, I have a float called `ratingDecimal`, and I use some conditions to compare it. Here is what the conditions look like:

```
    if (ratingDecimal >= 0.0) {

    if (ratingDecimal < 0.3 && ratingDecimal != 0.3) {

        ratingDecimal = 0.0;

        NSLog(@"bigger or equal to 0 and smaller than 0.3");
    }
}

if (ratingDecimal >= 0.3) {

    if (ratingDecimal < 0.8 && ratingDecimal != 0.8) {

        ratingDecimal = 0.5;

        NSLog(@"middle");
    }
}

if (ratingDecimal >= 0.8) {

    NSLog(@"bigger or equal to 0.8");

    ratingDecimal = 1.0;
}
```

Here is a weird problem. I have set the `ratingDecimal` to 0.8, the console logs `ratingDecimal` as:

> 0.8

but calls:

> middle

Which should only be called if `ratingDecimal` is bigger or equal to 0.3 but smaller than 0.8 and DOES NOT equal to 0.8.

The statement that should be getting called is:

```
if (ratingDecimal >= 0.8) {

NSLog(@"bigger or equal to 0.8"); 

ratingDecimal = 1.0;

}
```

But I do not see

> bigger or equal to 0.8

You are probably wondering why my conditions are so tedious and complex, they can be as simple as:

```
if (ratingDecimal >= 0.3  < 0.8)
```

They used to be like that but since this has never worked I kept on breaking the statement down and it is STILL acting weird.

Why is this happening!?

Here is an image example:

[image: PROBLEM]

Comment: If ratingDecimal < 0.3 then there is no point in checking whether ratingDecimal != 0.3. It _must_ be different from 0.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ratingDecimal` value is probably something like 0.7999999999999. When printed to the console, something is probably rounding it to 0.8, but the *comparison* still sees it as less than 0.8.

This is due to the binary nature of floating point numbers. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for extensive information on this.

Comment: It's the same reason it's very hard to get `3 * (1/3)` to equal `1` in decimal. There is no fixed-length decimal value that gives `1` when multiplied by `3`. In most fixed-length decimal systems `3 * (1/3)` will be printed as `1` but is internally `.999999..` and so will also test as less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

@Greg gave a good answer. I'd like to point out that you can write that code in a much clearer and simpler fashion:

```
if (ratingDecimal >= 0.0) {
    if (ratingDecimal < 0.3) {
        ratingDecimal = 0.0;

        NSLog(@"bigger or equal to 0 and smaller than 0.3");
    } else if (ratingDecimal < 0.8) {
        ratingDecimal = 0.5;

        NSLog(@"middle");
    } else {
        ratingDecimal = 1.0;

        NSLog(@"bigger or equal to 0.8");
    }
} else {
    // negative
}
```

As an FYI - a line such as:

```
if (ratingDecimal < 0.3 && ratingDecimal != 0.3) {
```

doesn't make such sense. If a number is less than 0.3 then it must be unequal to 0.3 so the second check doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I know that, in my question I say that the only reason I put that was to break the if statement and make 100 percent sure I was doing it right

Answer (score 0):

you can use functions like roundf() according to your need.